# Express Sessions 1.17.1+ ( req.session.myUserId )

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-session

I noticed changes in `express-session 1.17.1+` so I can't just put custom property (like `req.session.userId`)  into `req.session`. It causes a type check error.
I tried to extend SessionData, `Object.defineProperty` and many other options but for some reason, it doesn't work. Please help!

I wrote a simple code to reproduce problem clearly [here](https://github.com/itdimk/sht)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you, I share it with you to save time.

modify file `tsconfig.json` and add

```
"typeRoots": [
    "@types",
    "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

create file with following content: `@types/express/index.d.ts`

```
import "express-session";

// what we are all looking to solve xD
// req.session.propertyX
declare module "express-session" {
    interface SessionData {
        propertyX: number;
    }
}

// additional properties on other objects
// req.propertyY
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            propertyY: number;
        }
    }
}
```

hope it works for you, and saves time.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Then realized that behavior is changed in the latest release(https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/d1259ee31e6b17c31a5a86e27a0d12f3ec7c5a19#diff-0d13c95494fa97febecd0fbc1fb1b8f6e17bbcaedb8c88d10a0b655046e1c97b). Define the required fields as below to make it work.

```
declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData {
        userId: string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem.

There is a lot of discussion about this issue on the pull request. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/46576

In summary, in your `express-session.d.ts` file, you need to import the package and declare the module like below, so that declaration merging takes effect.

```js
import 'express-session';

declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: number;
  }
}
```

You then want to specify your `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json` file so the compiler picks up your custom declaration files.

Based on your repo, it looks like your `typeRoots` should be:

```json
"typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but so...

I have done these things right now and got the same error.
Weird thing is IDE doesn't see any errors like before, but typescript compiler does.

I've updated my repository with fixes you offered